# Login in to main app from active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I have app, and connected active admin. I'm trying to let admin user login as any user via active admin without password using devises's `sign_in @user` method. Is it possible to achieve this out of box?

I can make redirect with username in params/session, but that isnt secure, as if i wouldnt like to pass anything outside active admin.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can merger activeadmin users and existing users so that existing users with admin flag can sign into active admin. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253587/merging-activeadmin-users-with-existing-user-model

Comment: this is little bit different. I want my admin_user(s) to be able sign in as any user(via active admin)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "not secure"; the devise internals can make sure that you are an admin user, etc, and all you need to pass around is the username of the new user. That said, the code below is entirely within ActiveAdmin and will achieve what you want.

N.B. I can't think of an easy way to sign the Admin user back in (I use the same Devise for all users and use role-based auth).

```
member_action :sign_in_as, :method => :put do
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  sign_in user, bypass: true
  redirect_to root_path
end

action_item :only => :show do
  link_to('Sign in As', sign_in_as_admin_user_path(user), method: 'put')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using additional method to authenticate admin first like this,

```
def authenticate_any!
  if authenticate_admin_user!
    true
  else
    authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

or overriding devise

```
module Devise
 module Controllers
  module Helpers
   def authenticate_user!
    if authenticate_admin_user!
      return true
    end
    super
   end
  end
 end
end
```